# Processing the output of another XSLT Stylesheet

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT stylesheet that produces some output in XML. I want to processes that output with another stylesheet.  Is there a way to tell the latter stylesheet to "run and use" the results from the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not, as far as I know, a standard way to tell an XSLT processor to run another stylesheet on given input and do something with the output.  In some cases you can process the input against one set of templates and save the result in a variable, then apply a different set of templates to the value of the variable, something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="first-pass"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp" mode="second-pass"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you're running XSLT 2.0.  In XSLT 1.0 you will need a processor that supports the node-set extension (many do), and you'll need to change the reference to $temp to something like exslt:nodeset($temp).

As you will perceive, this won't work very well if your two stylesheets both use the default mode and operate on overlapping sets of element types.  So some XSLT processors have added extensions to provide the kind of functionality you describe (see, for example, discussions of the Xalan pipe:pipeDocument extension element).

Of course, you can also handle the pipe outside of XSLT.  The simplest way to do it depends upon the environment you are running in.

If you're running XSLT from an operating system shell and your XSLT processor accepts input on stdin, you can pipe the output from one stylesheet into the other:

```
xsltproc a.xsl in.xml | xsltproc b.xsl - > out.xml
```

And as mohammed moh has already pointed out, many scripting environments make it possible to do similar things:  he mentions PHP, and of course there's XProc.

Answer (score 0):

yes You can. You must Transforms the source node to a DOMDocument  I don't Know What is your Programming Language . For Example  in php is **transformToDoc()** after Transforms You Can Run A New XSLT Stylesheet On DOMDocument  Output